# Hadoop HUE Timeline Chart is Greyed Out

Tags: apache, hadoop, hue

I am trying to created a Timeline chart in HUE but it is greyed out and does not let me drag the Timeline chart onto the Dashboard.

I am able to create Text Facet, Pie Charts etc without problem but I am not able to create a Timeline chart.

Is Timeline expecting some sort of value or timestamp in the index?

[image: HUE Timeline Greyed Out]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We added a UTC timestamp field into the events we were sending so the timestamp ended up looking like for example :

```
"timestamp":"2015-11-02T00:14:58Z"
```

Looking at the index I could see this field showing up as type **tdate**

So on the solr container I changed the config :

/opt/solr/server/solr/configsets/data_driven_schema_configs/conf/solrconfig.xml

In the config I replaced :

```
<str name="fieldType">tdates</str>
```

With :

```
<str name="fieldType">tdate</str>
```

reloaded the container and sent new events, the Timeline button was enabled and I was able to drag it onto the dashboard.

The dashboard still doesn't look right though because the metric I want to display isn't showing up in the list of available fields.

Looking at the index the metric field is showing up as type **tlongs**

Comment: Upvoted because you found the solution and shared it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is expected a 'date' or 'tdate' field type (as the Timeline is based on a time X axis).

You can see some [example](https://github.com/cloudera/hue/tree/master/apps/search/examples/collections) in the code or directly in the Search examples (installable from the /about/#step2 page of Hue).

Comment: Hi Romain, I have got a _timestamp field now being added into solr that looks like 2015-10-28T20:09:56Z, in solr the field looks like [u'2015-10-28T20:09:56Z'], but the timeline button is still grey, do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: What is the Solr type?

Comment: I changed the config :

/opt/solr/server/solr/configsets/data_driven_schema_configs/conf/solrconfig.xml

In the config I replaced :

<str name="fieldType">tdates</str>
With :

<str name="fieldType">tdate</str>

Comment: Glad to hear! Did you have any reason to use tdates instead of tdate?

Comment: I think tdates was just configured as the default type for things that were detected as java.util.Date

 <lst name="typeMapping">
        <str name="valueClass">java.util.Date</str>
        <str name="fieldType">tdates</str>
      </lst>

so I just changed it to tdate.